# Do we have any command to get security update for ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, vulnerability

In Redhat/CentOS/OL there is direct command `yum updateinfo list sec` or `yum updateinfo list cve` to get security update from the repo, am searching the same for ubuntu as well. do we have any command for that?

I want output like the following:

```
SecurityUpdate_PackageName| SecurityUpdate_Version |SecurityUpdate_CVE
bind9 | host1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.19+esm3 | CVE-2022-2795
```

Answer (score 1):

This won’t produce exactly the output you’re looking for, but it’s the closest I know of. Install the `debsecan` package, then run

```
debsecan --suite $(lsb_release --codename --short) --source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BBVA/ust2dsa/data/ --only-fixed
```

to get a list of packages with available security fixes, and the details of the fixed CVEs.

`debsecan` has a variety of output formats, see `man debsecan` for details. Note that this isn’t an official Ubuntu tool; see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debsecan/+bug/95925) for details.